# Handling Immediate Return of WSARecv

Tags: c, windows, winapi, winsock, winsock2

I'm implementing an async server using `WSARecv`. According to the documentation, WSARecv can return immediately with `0`. This still eventually calls my completion routine, where I call `WSARecv` again to grab the rest of the data. If there is no more data to grab, I'd expect my subsequent call to `WSARecv` would result in its completion routine receiving `0` bytes in the second parameter.

So, I call the receive:

```
// ret is zero after this call.
int ret = WSARecv(socket, buf, 1, &RecvBytes, &Flags, overlapped, WorkerRoutine);
```

Eventually, this calls my completion routine `WorkerRoutine` where I do some work on the data and eventually call `WSARecv` again to get the remaining parts of the data.

```
void CALLBACK WorkerRoutine(DWORD recv_error, DWORD bytes, LPWSAOVERLAPPED overlapped, DWORD recv_flags)
{
    int         ret = 0;
    const char* error = 0;
    DWORD       num_bytes = 0;
    DWORD       flags = 0;

    if (recv_error != 0) {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // This is non-zero on the first call to the completion routine.
    if (bytes == 0) {
        return;
    }

    //... Omitted some data handling code.

    WSABUF buf;
    buf.buf = buffer;
    buf.len = buff_size;
    SecureZeroMemory(overlapped, sizeof(WSAOVERLAPPED));

    // ret is -1 here and WSAGetLastError() == WSA_IO_PENDING
    ret = WSARecv(sock, &buf, 1, &num_bytes, &flags, overlapped, WorkerRoutine);
```

If I send a small amount of data (< buff_size, e.g. 'hello'), the first call to `WSARecv` will return immediately. The completion routine is still called, but I don't cleanly exit the completion routine, and issue another `WSARecv`. I assumed that the second completion routine would eventually get called, where I could check if `bytes` was zero and exit if it was (without issuing another call to `WSARecv`). Instead, the second completion routine is never executed.

Is this a misunderstanding of how completion routines work? Is it safe to ignore the fact that the second completion routine never fires?

For completeness, I'm using a Python script to interact with my server:

```
import socket
import sys
import time

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
data = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])

# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    # Connect to server and send data
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sock.sendall(data + "\n")

    # Receive data from the server and shut down
    received = sock.recv(1024)
finally:
    sock.close()

print "Sent:     {}".format(data)
print "Received: {}".format(received)
```

Do I not get "end of data" because of how i'm interacting from Python?

Comment: "*If there is no more data to grab, I'd expect my subsequent call to WSARecv would result in its completion routine receiving 0 bytes in the second parameter.*" - no. Winsock will simply wait for new data to arrive, then issue a completion for it. The completion routine will not be triggered with 0 bytes unless the connection is closed gracefully by the peer

Comment: "*The completion routine is still called, but I don't cleanly exit the completion routine, and issue another WSARecv. I assumed that the second completion routine would eventually get called*" - there won't be a second completion issued. There is a 1:1 relationship between number of successful/pending `WSARecv` calls and subsequent completions, one for each buffer requested. If you don't call `WSARecv` again, there is nothing to complete

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is it correct, then, to track the message size? Perhaps by prepending it to the message and tracking how many bytes we have read so far in the completion routine? I'm confused by your second point. I call `WSARecv` again in the completion routine. It returns a `SOCKET_ERROR` but is a `WSA_IO_PENDING` - should I expect another completion in this case?

Comment: yes, you have to track the message size, to know when you have finished reading a complete message. It may take multiple receives to get everything. And yes, if you get `WSA_IO_PENDING` then you will get a completion event, whether the read operation ultimately succeeds or fails.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok, I think I was misunderstanding how completions worked. Just to be extra sure: If I issue a `WSARecv`, there will be a completion event, but only if the client actually sends more data (i.e. the completion may not actually trigger again). It is up to me to decide when an entire message has been received, and an outstanding `WSARecv` is intended to service additional data that may (or may not) arrive on the socket. Is that correct?

Comment: @Julio now you're getting it:)

Comment: @MartinJames - look like no, still not get

Comment: *If I issue a WSARecv, there will be a completion event, but only if the client actually sends more data* - this is huge mistake. no. if `WSARecv` return `TRUE` or `FALSE` with last error `WSA_IO_PENDING` (== `ERROR_IO_PENDING`) - will be completion event. and this absolute not depend from send other side some data or not.

Comment: @RbMM ok, then under what circumstances is a completion issued?

Comment: very different - when some data arrived, when connection will be broken, due you or remote side call disconnect, due cancel io request (CancalIo), due handle close. but you need clear understand - if you got `ERROR_IO_PENDING` - completion **always** must be

Comment: @Julio when an IO operation is pending, a completion event is issued when the operation is finished for ANY reason, success or fail

Answer (score 0):

If WSARecv returns -1 and GetLastError is something other than WSA_IO_PENDING then there won't be an asynchronous completion. If you want to handle that situation with an additional asynchronous operation you can schedule it yourself with QueueUserAPC or PostQueuedCompletionStatus.

Comment: Yes, in the second call to `WSARecv` i'm getting `SOCKET_ERROR`. I was mistaken, however (and updated the comment in the code), `WSAGetLastError` is returning `WSA_IO_PENDING`. So in this case, it *does* appear as though there will be an async completion, but it never happens... Why?

Comment: @Julio if `WSARecv` is successful but you don't get a completion issued, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `SOCKET_ERROR` with `WSA_IO_PENDING` is considered a success, no? So, I should expect a completion issued?

Comment: You are using an alertable wait on the thread that issued the WSARecv, right? Without that the second completion will be scheduled but never run.

Comment: *you can (and must) schedule it yourself with* direct call of `WorkerRoutine`. for what use `QueueUserAPC` when we direct can call `WorkerRoutine` on error ?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Yes, I'm using `SelectEx` to get things in an alertable state.

Comment: @Julio - think not `SelectEx` but `SleepEx` you using. however better instead apc completion, which require from you alertable wait and not exit from thread, which issued io, bind socket to iocp. with this you free do any tasks - anyway will be completion

Comment: @RbMM Whoops, yes, `SleepEx`.

Comment: @RbMm is right in saying that you would be much better off _not_ using completion routines and instead going the IOCP way. This will give you better control on how you want your callback(s) to be executed, and also make it easier for you do come up with a design that scales well. Basically, that comes down to doing CreateIoCompletionPort, and then GetQueuedCompletionStatus instead of SleepEx. I would avoid alertable-wait APC callbacks anywhere where it is possible to use other mechanisms.

Comment: @fbrosseau - all depends on the specific task. use APC completion not is bad and sometime can be the best choice. however with asynchronous sockets i think much better use IOCP by next reason - it is logical that all operations will be async and in same way. if in revc and send we have choice - APC or IOCP - for `ConnectEx` and `DisconnectEx` we have no choice - only IOCP. use APC for recv/send and IOCP for connect/disconnect (or make it synchronous) ? bad solution i think. so only one choice - use IOCP with sockets.

Comment: about `CreateIoCompletionPort` and listen on it threadpool yourself - this is better choice for servers, which have many sockets. if we implement client  - enough and much more simply use system suplied IOCP and callback via `BindIoCompletionCallback` or `CreateThreadpoolIo`

Comment: I do like APC in UI applications, using MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx as the main message loop driver (then obtain actual messages with PeekMessage.